# Folder configuration of gmail with alpine

Tags: gmail, alpine-mail

I'm using my Google account with Alpine. I only appear to have the "Inbox" folder - I haven't got "Trash", "Drafts", "Sent Mail" or "All Mails". Does anyone have any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Here my configuration:

```
Default Fcc (File carbon copy)    = {imap.gmail.com:993/user=mygoogleacc@gmail.com/ssl/novalidate-cert}[Gmail]/Sent Mail
Default Saved Message Folder      = {imap.gmail.com:993/user=mygoogleacc@gmail.com/ssl/novalidate-cert}[Gmail]/All Mail
Postponed Folder                  = {imap.gmail.com:993/user=mygoogleacc@gmail.com/ssl/novalidate-cert}[IMAP]/Drafts
Read Message Folder               = <No Value Set>
Form Letter Folder                = <No Value Set>
Trash Folder                      = {imap.gmail.com:993/user=mygoogleacc@gmail.com/ssl/novalidate-cert}[Gmail]/Trash
```

Answer (score 3):

When you select your Gmail account there should be a list of folders, including your labels. In my config, which is more or less default, there is a [Gmail]/ folder. This is the folder which contains 'drafts', 'spam', 'trash' etc.

Comment: can you post your config please....

Comment: sorry for the delay: http://pastebin.com/i5hU6hC2

Comment: p.s. I've copied this exact file to a fresh install of alpine and it works without amendment.

Comment: the python script here works a treat to get your gmail contacts into alpine: http://superuser.com/questions/55124/how-can-i-use-my-gmail-contacts-within-alpine-pine/164218#164218

Comment: i have the contacts already ;)