# Alpine - sync sent mail

Tags: email, sync, alpine-mail

My mail client can sync sent mail, independent of method used to send email (iphone, mail client, browser). But I'm finding that Alpine is only saving my sent mail that is sent using Alpine. How do I get Alpine to sync all sent mail?  Thanks in advance.

Below are some setting.

```
User Domain  = <No Value Set>

SMTP Server (for sending) = smtp.host.com/submit/novalidate-cert/user=name@company.com

Inbox Path = {imap.host.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert/user=name@company.com}inbox

Incoming Archive Folders          = <No Value Set>

Pruned Folders                    = <No Value Set>

Default Fcc (File carbon copy)    = <No Value Set: using "sent-mail">

Default Saved Message Folder      = <No Value Set: using "saved-messages">

Postponed Folder                  = <No Value Set: using "postponed-msgs">

Read Message Folder               = <No Value Set>

Form Letter Folder                = <No Value Set>

Trash Folder                      = <No Value Set: using "Trash">

Literal Signature                 = <No Value Set>

Signature File                    = <No Value Set: using ".signature">
```

Comment: How is Alpine connecting to your mail server?

Comment: Added some details. Let me know if I'm missing some info.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/q/199401/302 ( i.e. set Default Saved Message Folder)

Comment: I don't think it is a dup and if it is I'm not seeing the how to translate the what works for gmail to my situation.

Comment: So you'd change your `Default Saved Message Folder` to be something like `{imap.host.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert/user=name@company.com}sent`

Comment: Tried that, didn't work.

Comment: Did it not save to your "sent" folder, or fail with an error?

Comment: No error and no noticable differences.

Comment: I suggest to do the suggestion of Rowland Shaw for Default Fcc (File carbon copy).

Comment: Try to see what folder your other email client (iphone, browser, ...) use to save the sent-messages. Maybe they use other folders. Try to use the same folder for all your email client.

Answer (score 2):

To make Alpine use the same Sent folder that other email clients use, you would have to set the **Default Fcc (File carbon copy) folder** (where Alpine copies sent mail) to a folder on your IMAP server. Something like this:

```
{imap.host.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert/user=name@company.com}Sent
```

Here's the Alpine documentation:

> This value specifies where a copy of outgoing mail should be saved. If this is not a path name, it will be in the default collection for saves. Any valid folder specification, local or IMAP, is allowed. This default folder carbon copy only applies when the "Fcc Name Rule" is set to use the default folder. Unix Alpine default is normally "sent-mail" in the default folder collection.
>
> If you access your email through an IMAP server, especially if you often switch between Unix Alpine and PC-Alpine, or between various desktop email systems, you may want to set this to a folder on your IMAP server (remember that in order to later access this remote folder through Alpine, it must be in a folder collection. See Folder Collections Explained for more information).

Comment: "/novalidate-cert"?

Comment: `novalidate-cert` hides certificate warnings (if you use a self-signed certificate on your IMAP server) or, in my case, OpenSSL bubbletext. This text pops up when you connect and disrupts the Alpine interface, which is a little jarring when you're typing in your password.

Comment: For my company (using outlook 365) the following setting was valid (without quotes): "{outlook.office.de:993/ssl/novalidate-cert/user=me@company.de}Gesendete Elemente"